# Неправильно вычисляется проверка на подмножество, при вызове метода get вместо символов получаются знаки равно

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, операторы

Неправильно вычисляется проверка на подмножество, при вызове метода get вместо символов получаются знаки равно. Как это исправить?

Написал класс Set - множество, добавил в него перегрузку операции проверки на подмножество `>`, но она не работает как нужно, при вызове метода get в ней получаются знаки равно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программный код:

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Set.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Set set;
    set + 'a';
    set + 'b';

    Set set_2;
    set_2 + 'k';
    set_2 + 'b';

    set.print(); // содержимое set
    set_2.print(); // содержимое set_2

    cout << set.get(1) << endl; // получение элемента по индексу

    (set > set_2).print(); // пересечение множеств 

}
```

**Set.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#define maxlength 10
using namespace std;

class Set {
    char* s; // указатель на начало массива
    int power = 0; // текущий размер массива
public:
    Set();
    Set(int POWER);
    Set(const Set& cs);
    ~Set();
    char get(int i);
    int length();
    int index(char ch);
    void print();
    Set& operator=(Set& v);
    void operator +(char a); // добавить элемент в множество
    friend Set operator>(Set sf, Set ss); // проверка на подмножество
    Set operator -(char a);
};
```

**Set.cpp:**

```
#include "Set.h"

Set::Set()
{
    s = new char[maxlength];
    power = 0;
}

Set::Set(int POWER)
{
    s = new char[maxlength];
    power = POWER;

}

Set::Set(const Set& cs)
{
    s = new char[maxlength];
    power = cs.power;
    for (int i = 0; i < power; i++)
        s[i] = get(i);
}

Set::~Set()
{
    delete[] s;
}

char Set::get(int i)
{
    return s[i];
}

int Set::length()
{
    return power;
}

int Set::index(char ch)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
        if (ch == s[i]) {
            return i;
        }
            
    }
        
}

void Set::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < power; i++)
        cout << s[i] << ' ';
    cout << "" << endl;
}

Set& Set::operator=(Set& v)
{
    if (this != &v)
    {
        power = v.power;
        delete[] s;
        s = new char[maxlength];
        for (int i = 0; i < v.power; ++i)
        {
            s[i] = v.s[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

void Set::operator+(char a)
{
        if (power < maxlength) {
            s[power] = a; 
            power++;
        }
        
}

Set Set::operator-(char a)
{
    Set set;
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
        ch = this->get(i);
        if (a != ch) {
            set + ch;
        }       
    }   
    return set;
}

Set operator>(Set sf, Set ss)
{
    int i, j;
    Set tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < sf.power; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < ss.power; j++)
            if (sf.get(i) == ss.get(j))
                tmp + ss.get(j);
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Откровенно говоря, то, что вы написали, лучше делать просто со строками - вы же все равно даже не проверяете при вставке, нет ли уже такого элемента во множестве. Кстати, это уже дело семантики операторов - число на глаз - `a+b` так и просит присваивания, нет? А вот `a += b` не просило бы. Лучше бы вы оператор `+=` перегружали. Как и `>` так и вызывает ассоциацию не с пересечением (тут лучше был бы оператор `*`), а со сравнением размеров, например...

Comment: @Harry перегрузил оператор " =", мне пока сложно во всем этом разобраться, недавно только начал с++ изучать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас передача в оператор `>` по значению, так что посмотрим на конструктор копирования внимательнее...

```
Set::Set(Set& cs)    // Конечно, лучше бы передавать по константной ссылке - вряд ли вы 
                     // собираетесь менять копируемое множество... ну да ладно
{
    s = new char[maxlength];   // Отлично, выделена память
    power = cs.length();       // Размер равен копируемому
    for (int i = 0; i < power; i++)
        s[i] = get(i);         // Поскольку get(i) по сути и есть s[i], копируем... 
                               // выделенный массив с мусором сам в себя (!)
}
```

Все, вопросов больше нет?

А у меня есть - что вам стоило, получив проблему, начать с того, что добавить в проблемный код отладочный вывод

```
Set operator>(Set sf, Set ss)
{
    sf.print();
    ss.print();
    int i, j;
    Set tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < sf.power; i++)
```

и сразу увидеть, что множества в операторе совсем не те, что вы передаете? **Как** вы вообще пытались справиться с проблемой? Как отлаживали код?

Comment: Спасибо большое, впердь буду внимательнее. А как реализуется проверка на подмножество? вы писали что это больше походит на пересечение

Comment: *Впердь* не надо :), просто учитесь отлаживать программу. Я показал, как это можно было сделать проще всего в вашем случае - даже без отладчика. Не стесняйтесь выводить отладочную информацию - это помогает в локализации ошибки. Ну, а если ответ вас устраивает - то закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ - птичка слева от него...

Comment: А как реализуется проверка на подмножество? вы писали что это больше походит на пересечение

Comment: Проверка, что А есть подмножество Б - возвращает true или false; А - подмножество Б, если все элементы А имеются в Б.